# Navigation bar at the top shows some background color around/above it

Tags: html, css

Take a look at the image attached to this question.

Red Nav Bar has black on top:
[image: Red Nav Bar has black on top]

You see how there is black color around the navigation bar at the top of the page. It looks like it is floating?

How do I make it so that it is all red from edge to edge and all the way to the top of the page?

Here is my page code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

h1 {
  color: red;
}
.nav {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-width: px 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 35px;
  float: clear;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline;
}
.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
li {
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 65%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/videos.php">Videos</a></li>
  <li><a href="/images.php">Images</li>
      <li><a href="/clients/">Clients</a></li>
  <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: default body margin. remove it with: `body { margin: 0; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 solutions below...

You can choose margin zero for all by the css below.

```
*{ margin: 0} //this is for all margins.
```

OR

```
body { margin:0} //this is for only body margin
```

OR

select "Position: absolute" for the nav element with top, left, right zero

```
.nav{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: why make it so complicated with side efefcts if the issue is way more simple? its just a default body margin that can be removed by setting it to 0. just 1 line of code.

Comment: yes you are right. that's another option I have added both.

Comment: ok just use body instead of all. All also has side effects that it removes default margins you might actually want to have.